# Ionic 2 - Ion-Select - How to select an option by default?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

See the following code:

```
<ion-item no-lines no-padding [ngClass]="{'ddl-selected': (detailedNote.content.m1spasm.tmj)}">
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="detailedNote.content.m1spasm.tmj" class="ddl-custom">
    <ion-option [value]="''">TMJ</ion-option>
    <ion-option [value]="'TMJ left'">TMJ Left</ion-option>
    <ion-option [value]="'TMJ right'">TMJ Right</ion-option>
    <ion-option [value]="'TMJ bilateral'">TMJ Bilateral</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Is there any way that I could set an option by default? Like in the following example:

```
<option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
```

I need to select the first option as a default: TMJ. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Emi you can set `detailedNote.content.m1spasm.tmj` modal value in ts file

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using words with blank spaces for the values, and since they are static values, you can use the `value` attribute directly (instead of the angular property `[value]`):

```
<ion-item no-lines no-padding [ngClass]="{'ddl-selected': (detailedNote.content.m1spasm.tmj)}">
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="detailedNote.content.m1spasm.tmj" class="ddl-custom">
    <ion-option value="tmj">TMJ</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="tmj_left">TMJ Left</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="tmj_right">TMJ Right</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="tmj_bilateral">TMJ Bilateral</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

So now in order to select the first option by default (the one with the `value` attribute equal to `tmj`), in the constructor or in any other function from the component, initialize the `detailedNote.content.m1spasm.tmj` property with that value:

```
constructor(...) {
  this.detailedNote.content.m1spasm.tmj = 'tmj';
}
```

Comment: I see. I thought there was a simpler method of doing it.  But it works this way as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To select an `ion-option` by default, you could use the `selected` property, just like a html5 `option` tag:

`<ion-select>
   <ion-option value="AL">Albania</ion-option>
   <ion-option value="YE" selected>Yemen</ion-option>
   <ion-option value="AF">Afghanistan</ion-option>
</ion-select>`